# Processes and permissions

Tags: windows, unix, permissions, file-permissions

I am having trouble understanding processes and permissions.

Do all executable have an owner?

If so then does the process have the permissions of the owner of the process or the person executing?

For example, I write a script to change passwords that requires admin level privileges. I am an `admin` so call me **USER-A** but for some reason I give `non admin` **user-b** permission to run my script. Will the script execute if **user-b** is not an `admin`?

Comment: A process executed by a system user has that user's level of permissions and can only access files/directories that user has access to. On nix, there is rwx as permission bits, so even if a user may not have rw privileges for a script, that user can still have x privileges to run it. However, if that script needs to log into /var/log and that user doesn't have rights to write into /var/log, the script won't be able to log when that user executes it.

Comment: What @MaQleod indicates about nix also applies to Windows in many cases.  By default a process ran by user, has the same permission as the user, unless the permissions of that process are specifically elevated by that user.  You can of course, launch a process specifically as an Administrator, to skip that protection.  You would still need to authenticate as that Administrator user obviously.